# Getting issue in delete operation using PHP and Angular.js

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have a issue in delete operation using PHP and angular.js. Here i need to show alert prompt before user deleted.In this alert prompt if i will click on ok button the user will delete and if i will click on cancel button it will not delete anything.I have done some coding which i am explaining below.

```
<a ui-sref='dashboard.role'>
<input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-red' value='Delete' ng-click="deleteRoleData(role.id);" ng-confirm-click="Are you sure to delete this user role ?" >  
</a>
```

> rolecontroller.js:

```
var dashboard=angular.module('Channabasavashwara');
dashboard.controller('roleController',function($scope,$http,$state){
$scope.deleteRoleData=function(rid){
        id=rid;
        var userdata={'userid':id};
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "php/userrole/deleteRoleData.php",
            data:userdata,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(function successCallback(response){
            //console.log('delete',response);
            alert(response.data);
            $state.go('dashboard.role',{}, { reload: true });
        },function errorCallback(response) {
            alert(response.data);
            $state.go('dashboard.role',{}, { reload: true });
        });
    }
})
dashboard.directive('ngConfirmClick', [
  function() {
    return {
      priority: 1,
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        var msg = attr.ngConfirmClick || "Are you sure?";
        var clickAction = attr.ngClick;
        attr.ngClick = "";
        element.bind('click', function(event) {
          if (window.confirm(msg)) {
            scope.$eval(clickAction)
          }
        });
      }
    };
  }
])
```

Here my problem is when user will click on cancel button the data also will delete from DB which should not happen.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the controller to the directive and use it like this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/0gara8q0/1/)

HTML:

```
<input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-red' value='Delete' role="role.id" ng-confirm-click="Are you sure to delete this user role ?">
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.directive('ngConfirmClick', [
function () {
    return {
        controller: function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.deleteRoleData = function (rid) {
                id = rid;
                var userdata = {
                    'userid': id
                };
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: "php/userrole/deleteRoleData.php",
                    data: userdata,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    }
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    //console.log('delete',response);
                    alert(response.data);
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    alert(response.data);
                });
            }
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            var msg = attr.ngConfirmClick || "Are you sure?";
            var role = attr.role;
            attr.ngClick = "";
            element.bind('click', function (event) {
                if (window.confirm(msg)) {
                    scope.deleteRoleData(role);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

PS I removed `$state` only for JSFiddle

Comment: @ Michelem : I also have many other functions inside controller which have not given here.Is there any problem ?

Comment: @ Michelem : I added your code but still issue is there.

Comment: If you check the JSFiddle it works fine, so you probably have something different.

Comment: The problem in general, is the ng-click, as soon as the user click it the ng-click is triggered, so you have to remove that and trigger it only from the directive.